# JQuery ,replaceWith() not working after writing to session from iframe, unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, session, iframe

I have a function that rewrites dynamically a div after ajax call

```
    function showPage(href){
    setTitle("",0);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: href,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            rewriteContentDiv(html,isNotFade);
        }
    });
}


function rewriteContentDiv(html, href,  isNotFade) {
    var bodyObj;
    if($('#content-div').length !=0){bodyObj=document.body;}else{bodyObj=parent.document.body;}

    $('#content-div', bodyObj).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        var div = $('<div class="content" id="content-div">test2</div>').hide();
        div.html(html);
        $('#content-div', bodyObj).replaceWith(div);
        $('#content-div', bodyObj).fadeIn("slow");
        $('#content-div', bodyObj).find("a").click(function (e) { catchAnchorClick($(this), e) });
    });   
}
```

I call this function from a page and it works, unless 1 specific circumstance:
When inside the "content-div" I have an iframe with a button which writes something to a session with

```
function setObject(key,value){ 
       var session = window.sessionStorage;
       session.setItem(key, escape(JSON.stringify(value))); 
}
```

The object does get written to the session, but then the rewriteContentDiv function starts to fail on

```
$('#content-div', bodyObj).replaceWith(div);
```

line, without showing any exception or letting me step into the jQuery function - i debug on chrome  30.0.1599.101 m.

If I press "refresh" - the function starts working again, and I see the object in the session storage.

Why can it be and what can be done to prevent it?

I tried to make an ugly trick of  setting

> "window.location="

to the url of itself when in the problematic situation, but it didn't help...

Thanks.

Comment: `if(('#content-div').checkLength ==0)` missing $ sign in front of this if statement? By the way what is checkLength (did you mean length ) ?

Comment: huh... i really wrote these weird things... how did it work at all?! sorry, edited to a normal version... it didn't sole the problem though, the browser gets stuck on .replaceWith(div) line.

Comment: $('#content-div, ' + bodyObj) does not make sense, you are trying to concat a string with a raw HTML object ... Try this instead `$('#content-div, ' , bodyObj)`

Comment: someone edited my typo back to the code... please don't do it... i edited the code and it does $('#content-div', bodyObj), but it's not where the problem is.

Comment: you should really post the actual code instead of code you say is the code, especially when the sample code you post is full of errors that might cause the issue you are seeing

Comment: What's the purpose of bodyObj. You've already located the content div once why don't you just assign that selection to a local?

Comment: @RuneFS Got it (thanks to your question)! The weirdness was because after pressing button, the handler which called to rewriteContentDiv was set from inside the iframe, and that caused problems! ok, but how do I trigger changes in the outer body from the inner iframe without causing problems? Or that's bad practice? I put it to the iframe because there is a library of SliderKit and it somehow interfered with the css of the website, so I decided to disconnect between them with an iframe...

Answer (score 0):

Check the code once again as there are some grammar errors

```
function showPage (href){

    setTitle("",0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            rewriteContentDiv(html, href, isNotFade);
        }
    });

}

function rewriteContentDiv (html, href,  isNotFade) {

    var bodyObj;
    if ($('#content-div').length > 0) {
       bodyObj = document.body;
    } else {
       bodyObj = parent.document.body;
    }

    $('#content-div', bodyObj).fadeOut("slow", function () {
        var div = $('<div class="content" id="content-div">test2</div>').hide();
        div.html(html);
        $('#content-div', bodyObj).replaceWith(div);
        $('#content-div', bodyObj).fadeIn("slow");
        $('#content-div', bodyObj).find("a").click(function (e) { 
            catchAnchorClick($(this), e) });
        });   

}
```

Comment: $('#content-div, ' + bodyObj) causes Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #content-div, [object HTMLBodyElement], i use  $('#content-div',bodyObj) and it works (most of the time...(